# Drools - no suitable constructor found (long type argument)

Tags: drools

I'm trying to create a simple rule with Drools 7.37.0.

```
declare InputInformation
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
end

declare ServiceInformation
    @serialVersionUID( 0 )
    code: String @key
    text : String
    associations : List
end

rule "Match first and last name"
when 
    InputInformation(firstName == "John", lastName == "Doe")
then 
   insert( new ServiceInformation("123456", "ServiceTest", new ArrayList()) );
end
```

The error I get is related to the available (or rather not available) constructors for ServiceInformation:

```
constructor ServiceInformation() is not applicable
[ERROR]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[ERROR]     constructor ServiceInformation(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.List,long) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[ERROR]     constructor ServiceInformation(java.lang.String) is not applicable
```

Where does the "long" parameter type in the second constructor come from, since it's not declared in the fact?

Comment: I debugged and it seems @serialVersionUID( 0 ) is added to the constructor.
It shouldn't be the case since it's static...

Comment: I'm looking at the drools documentation and see no indication that `@serialVersionUID` is implemented as static.

Comment: It might not be documented but it's a static field in the generated class.

Comment: If it's static and not static final, then its presence is not entirely unexpected in the all-args constructor, given how drools does serialization. It is unexpected of course for regular developers who are used to proper Java. You can open a bug with the drools library is you think it a significant issue. That said, most people do seem to use the default no-arg constructor for declared types.